# How to remove canvas background and display full background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, background

I am following this [tutorial](http://codepen.io/loktar00/pen/uEJKl) and trying to implement it on my website. I am struggling to remove the 'Black' background to show the full background image with the stars.

Here's jsFiddle: [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aernk8kk/4/)

Here's the screen shot below.

[image]

Here's the jQuery for your inspection:

```
  width = window.innerWidth,
  height = 300;

  // Add 2 shooting stars that just cycle.
  entities.push(new ShootingStar());
  entities.push(new ShootingStar());

  //animate background
  function animate() {
  bgCtx.fillStyle = "black";
  bgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  bgCtx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  bgCtx.strokeStyle = "#fff";

  var entLen = entities.length;

  while (entLen--) {
      entities[entLen].update();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  animate();
```

Any help would be great! thanks :)

Comment: Too much code. Could you narrow it down to where you calculate the background size as well as paint it (I'm pretty sure the shooting stars are ok - looks nice btw). The rest we'll find in the fiddle.

Comment: sorry about that and thanks :) .. I have very little knowledge about jQuery, I've edited the code above and I assume that it is doing what you had asked for :) thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `animate()`function, replace

```
  bgCtx.fillStyle = "black";
  bgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

with

```
  bgCtx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
  bgCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

and remove this line `bgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);`(l80)

http://jsfiddle.net/aernk8kk/13/

```js
  (function () {
      var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
              window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
      window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
  })();

  // Terrain stuff.
  var background = document.getElementById("bgCanvas"),
      bgCtx = background.getContext("2d"),
      width = window.innerWidth,
      height = 300;

  (height < 400) ? height = 400 : height;

  background.width = width;
  background.height = height;

  function Terrain(options) {
      options = options || {};
      this.terrain = document.createElement("canvas");
      this.terCtx = this.terrain.getContext("2d");
      this.scrollDelay = options.scrollDelay || 90;
      this.lastScroll = new Date().getTime();

      this.terrain.width = width;
      this.terrain.height = height;
      this.fillStyle = options.fillStyle || "#f30";
      this.mHeight = options.mHeight || height;

      // generate
      this.points = [];

      var displacement = options.displacement || 140,
          power = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(width) / (Math.log(2))));

      // set the start height and end height for the terrain
      this.points[0] = this.mHeight;//(this.mHeight - (Math.random() * this.mHeight / 2)) - displacement;
      this.points[power] = this.points[0];

      // create the rest of the points
      for (var i = 1; i < power; i *= 2) {
          for (var j = (power / i) / 2; j < power; j += power / i) {
              this.points[j] = ((this.points[j - (power / i) / 2] + this.points[j + (power / i) / 2]) / 2) + Math.floor(Math.random() * -displacement + displacement);
          }
          displacement *= 0.6;
      }

      document.body.appendChild(this.terrain);
  }

  Terrain.prototype.update = function () {
      // draw the terrain
      this.terCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      this.terCtx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
      
      if (new Date().getTime() > this.lastScroll + this.scrollDelay) {
          this.lastScroll = new Date().getTime();
          this.points.push(this.points.shift());
      }

      this.terCtx.beginPath();
      for (var i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
          if (i === 0) {
              this.terCtx.moveTo(0, this.points[0]);
          } else if (this.points[i] !== undefined) {
              this.terCtx.lineTo(i, this.points[i]);
          }
      }

      this.terCtx.lineTo(width, this.terrain.height);
      this.terCtx.lineTo(0, this.terrain.height);
      this.terCtx.lineTo(0, this.points[0]);
      this.terCtx.fill();
  }


  // Second canvas used for the stars
  bgCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";


  // stars
  function Star(options) {
      this.size = Math.random() * 2;
      this.speed = Math.random() * .05;
      this.x = options.x;
      this.y = options.y;
  }

  Star.prototype.reset = function () {
      this.size = Math.random() * 2;
      this.speed = Math.random() * .05;
      this.x = width;
      this.y = Math.random() * height;
  }

  Star.prototype.update = function () {
      this.x -= this.speed;
      if (this.x < 0) {
          this.reset();
      } else {
          bgCtx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
      }
  }

  function ShootingStar() {
      this.reset();
  }

  ShootingStar.prototype.reset = function () {
      this.x = Math.random() * width;
      this.y = 0;
      this.len = (Math.random() * 80) + 10;
      this.speed = (Math.random() * 10) + 6;
      this.size = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.1;
      // this is used so the shooting stars arent constant
      this.waitTime = new Date().getTime() + (Math.random() * 3000) + 500;
      this.active = false;
  }

  ShootingStar.prototype.update = function () {
      if (this.active) {
          this.x -= this.speed;
          this.y += this.speed;
          if (this.x < 0 || this.y >= height) {
              this.reset();
          } else {
              bgCtx.lineWidth = this.size;
              bgCtx.beginPath();
              bgCtx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
              bgCtx.lineTo(this.x + this.len, this.y - this.len);
              bgCtx.stroke();
          }
      } else {
          if (this.waitTime < new Date().getTime()) {
              this.active = true;
          }
      }
  }

  var entities = [];

  // init the stars
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      entities.push(new Star({
          x: Math.random() * width,
          y: Math.random() * height
      }));
  }

  // Add 2 shooting stars that just cycle.
  entities.push(new ShootingStar());
  entities.push(new ShootingStar());

  //animate background
  function animate() {
      bgCtx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
      bgCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      bgCtx.fillStyle = '#fff';
      bgCtx.strokeStyle = "#fff";

      var entLen = entities.length;

      while (entLen--) {
          entities[entLen].update();
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  animate();
```

```css
body, html {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(


http://cdn1.dottech.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/moon_clear_sky_wallpaper_2560x1440.jpg

   ) no-repeat center center fixed;




 

   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}


canvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0
}
```

```html
<canvas id="bgCanvas"></canvas>
```

check [`clearRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect)